# Are there any kshatriyas that don't trace descent from Solar or Lunar dynasties?

Tags: puranas, kshatriya, chandravansh, suryavansh, genealogy

Is there any Kshatriya group that doesn't trace its descent from Solar or Lunar dynasties?

Agnivansh is a prominent group amongst Rajputs, but any apart from these mentioned in Puranas or Vedas.

Comment: Some might say the ones from Surabhi the cow, but technically only their mother is known.